# Setting up development environment in Windows 10 without admin rights

Tags: security, windows-10, admin

Let me give a quick background of the work I do and then I'll explain the problem I am facing.

I am a software developer with more than 15+ years work experience. My work involves a lot of varied tasks:

- data analysis using R, Python
- development of web applications using Ruby on Rails, JS, etc.
- building models using open source libraries
  So far, I have been doing all this  in my personal laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) and have faced no issues.

But I would soon need to start using a laptop provided by the organisation that I am working for. This org is not a IT company, it's a public body. They only use Windows (10) and don't provide admin access to anyone. It's very hard to get permission to install any kind of "approved" software. Just to give an example, they refused to install Chrome in my laptop as they wouldn't be able to control the updates.

So here's my problem - what do I do to work peacefully using their laptop? The primary reason I have to use the work laptop is that there are a lot of important documents kept in shared drives that are accessible only in their machines.

I have been looking at options like WSL or Hyper-V. But, before I put in a request to the IT team to get them to agree, I wanted to know a few things:

1) Which among WSL or Hyper-V would be the better approach for setting up the dev environment that I want?

2) IF I get the IT team to install WSL/HV, would I be able to set up everything else without having to go back to them for each software? Is there a way of secure local admin access these options would provide that will ease their concerns?

3) Is there some other way of setting up what I want?

Comment: If execution of downloaded portable software is possible/allowed you should check what programs of your development stack is available as portable software - I would assume that a large part of them is available. Anyway the main question is what is the target platform your developed apps will run on?

Comment: Nope, not possible to install portable software. E.g. I downloaded the RStudio executable file. When I try to run it (to install), it asks for Admin credentials (which I don't have) :|

The target platform for my developed apps are very varied. I would need to deploy some web-apps on an (AWS) Ubuntu server. In other cases, I would just need to perform data analysis and export my findings in a format (document/spreadsheet) that other colleagues can use.

Comment: If it asks for admin permissions you don't have a portable version. Anyway a locked down Windows machine is not a good development machine. You are not a user you are a developer. Ask your admins for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If still applicable and actual I can share my solution:
If you should work on a windows machine where you don’t have administrative privileges, you can very easily make a portable R/Rstudio installation.

Download a recent version of R from the CRAN site and the recent version of RStudio. After download extract RStudio installation exec with 7Zip and copy files from $_OUTDIR to the desired location (in case you making an update, simply overwrite all files, that already exist). Your RStudio executable will be in

```
your-chosen-directory/bin/rstudio.exe
```

Then run CRAN-R installation, ignore the warning that you don’t have administrative privileges and go forward until installation will complete. Run RStudio, from the menu

```
Tools->Global Options
```

locate where your R installation is located.

If you performing an update (more recent version of R), copy all files from the library subfolder of the old R installation into new, but this time DON’T OVERWRITE! This operation vill preserves the packages you have installed in the previous version of R. After copying update all your packages from the RStudio window (Packages->Update). When the packages update process will end check which packages failed to update (You will see warning messages near them in the RStudio console). Remove these packages (write down names of failed packages and delete corresponding folders from library subfolder). For this, you will need to exit from RStudio. After deletion launch RStudio again and execute the packages install command in the RStudio console:

```
install.packages(c("package1", "package2", "package3"))
```

Congratulations, You are ready to go!